# How to change a list of strings to a list of integers

Tags: python, scripting

I'm writing a program that takes a user file (a list of numbers, in this case) and calculate the mean, median, and mode of the list. However, I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to convert the number strings into integers. When I try, I get the error: "Invalid literal for int() in base 10" and then the first number of my list. No matter what I try I can't seem to convert the list even though this is the solution I keep seeing. Because of this, when I sort my list, it does not sort in numerical order. My mode function also seems to not be working very well, and even after a few days I can't figure out why. I would attach the file but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that, sorry. Hopefully this is enough information to see what might be causing the issues.

```
def CalculateMode(numbers):
    dictionary = dict()
    for num in numbers:
        if num in dictionary:
            dictionary[num] = dictionary[num] + 1
        else:
            dictionary[num] = 1
        maximum = max(dictionary.values())
        for key in dictionary:
            if dictionary[key] == maximum:
                print("The mode is " + key + ".")

def Main():
    openFile = open("testfile.txt", 'r')
    data = openFile.read()
    numbers = data.split()
    for num in numbers:
        num = int(num)
        return num
    numbers = sorted(numbers)
    print(numbers)
    while True:
        choice = input("Calculate Mode [1]  Exit [2]: ")
        if choice == "1":
            CalculateMode(numbers)
        elif choice == "2":
            break
        else:
            print("Please choose one of the above options.")

Main()
```

Comment: your code returns after trying to convert to an integer which is why nothing below runs. also how is the text file structured

Comment: The text file is structured as a list of numbers that looks like this: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
They are separated by a comma and a space.

Comment: when you split then you leave a trailing comma after each number hence why it fails. you will need to do `split(',')` to split on the comma

Comment: if the data is a string such as "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" then data.split() will produce ["1,", "2,", "3,", "4,", "5,"].  If you split on "," i.e. data.split(',') this will produce integers [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].  Howver, you would stil have issues if with "\n".  Could you post several lines of the data so we can provide better feedback?

Comment: Can there be newlines in the file? Or is it only a single line? Are the numbers integers only, or can there be floating point numbers also?

Answer (score 1):

One option using as much of your code as possible is the following.

Note: Renamed variables to following the Python convention [Pep 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) which is:

> Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability.
>
> Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

**Code**

```
import re

def calculate_mode(numbers):
    dictionary = dict()
    for num in numbers:
        if num in dictionary:
            dictionary[num] = dictionary[num] + 1
        else:
            dictionary[num] = 1

    maximum = max(dictionary.values())

    for key in dictionary:
        if dictionary[key] == maximum:
            print(f"The mode is {key}.")

def main():
    with open("testfile.txt", 'r') as open_file:
      # Extract consecutive digits using regex 
      # (see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-extract-numbers-from-string/)
      data = re.findall(r"\d+", open_file.read())

      # Convert digits to integer
      numbers = [int(x) for x in data]

    # Sort numbers (inplace)
    numbers.sort()

    print(numbers)
    while True:
        choice = input("Calculate Mode [1]  Exit [2]: ")
        if choice == "1":
            calculate_mode(numbers)
        elif choice == "2":
            break
        else:
            print("Please choose one of the above options.")


main()
```

**Input File (testfile.txt)**

```
2, 3, 4, 5,
7, 9, 3, 2
1, 2, 9, 5
4, 2, 1, 8
6, 3, 4, 5
```

**Output**

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9]
Calculate Mode [1]  Exit [2]: 1
The mode is 2.
Calculate Mode [1]  Exit [2]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cast using `int(float(desired_string))`

The string you're trying to cast is not convertible to int.

Edit: As gold_cy said, there is a logical inconsistency in your code that goes beyond the error presented.